# negative sentence, does do a non-a VS does not do a

Tags: negation

I read document at this link, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge

The following sentence I don't know why they write the way:

> Often the current branch head is an ancestor of the named commit. This is the most common case especially when invoked from git pull: you are tracking an upstream repository, **you have committed no local changes**, and now you want to update to a newer upstream revision.

Why don't they write "you have not committed any changes" ? Is there any idioms?

Comment: _Have done no..._ is more concise and sounds more professional than _have not done any..._.

Comment: @KateBunting Why? as I think they are the same meaning

Comment: Because it's more concise, as I said (it uses fewer words). Yes, they do have  the same meaning.

Comment: Because "***you have committed** no changes*" is a *positive assertion*, whereas "***you have not committed** any changes*" is a *negative assertion*. Positive assertions sound stronger and more precise.